# Open a CSV file with custom delimiter

Tags: excel, vba

I have a MAIN.xlsm with a macro called "open_input_workbook" which opens a CSV file.

The problem is that when I open the file using that macro, the file doesn't respect the columns, I'll show you with some screenshots:

input.csv open doing Double-Click on it:

[image: opened with double click]

input.csv open with the macro:

[image: opened with macro]

Macro Code:

```
Sub Open_input_Workbook()
  Workbooks.Open "C:\input.csv"
End Sub
```

Any help is welcome.

Thank you for your time

Comment: You need to [set the delimiter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.workbooks.open) to ```;``` the default is ```,``` on a csv.

Comment: Tried with the next code: Workbooks.Open "C:\_Disco_local\_Proyectos\AppMacroExcel\input.csv", Delimiter = ";"   but still doing the same @Warcupine

Comment: You might need to save it as a ```.txt``` then reopen it with ```openworkbooks```. You can try to use ```format = 4``` but I think the formatting of the csv is already messed up.

Comment: Try using `Workbooks.Open "C:\input.csv", Local:= True`

Answer (score 1):

try to use Workbooks.OpenText instead of the open command. That will allow you to set the delimiter.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.workbooks.opentext